# I need a better word for this than "snoutband"

Tags: synonyms

According to [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/slideshows/12-insults-we-should-bring-back#Snoutband):

> A snoutband is someone who always interrupts a conversation to correct or contradict the person speaking. Every social group has a snoutband, who thinks they know everything. They probably don't know the meaning of this word, though. At least, not yet.

But nobody uses this word!  There has to be a more formal, more appropriate synonym.

Comment: Related: [One word for someone who thinks they can do anything, and believes everything they do is right but others are wrong](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165899/one-word-for-someone-who-thinks-they-can-do-anything-and-believes-everything-th) (where _know-it-all_ is given).

Comment: Are you looking for the sort of person who interrupts rudely because they think they're better/smarter than the person speaking or because they think that person is wrong?  Or perhaps someone who isn't trying to be rude and just wants to add information or is trying to helpfully correct the person speaking?  I would go with "know-it-all" for the former, as @orangesandlemons mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would describe such a person as *nitpicky* and *pedantic*.

**nitpicky**

1. Finicky; overly critical; concerned with insignificant details.

**pedantic** (comparative more pedantic, superlative most pedantic)

1. Like a pedant, overly concerned with formal rules and trivial points of learning.
2. Being showy of one’s knowledge, often in a boring manner.
3. Being finicky or fastidious, especially with language.

You could use nominal forms and call such a person a nitpicky pedant or pedantic nitpicker. You could forgo one of the words in description, but people should understand what is meant.

Comment: I think I like pedantic the best.

Comment: I think I do as well.

Answer (score 3):

> who thinks they know everything

In British usage we [have know-it-all](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/know-it-all) or Know-all

Answer (score 2):

**Buttinsky**

> :  a person given to butting in :  a troublesome meddler
>
> there's always some buttinsky who has to tell you there's a better way to do whatever you're doing

"Buttinsky." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 3 May 2017.