# Word describing person who discourages somebody without evidence

Tags: meaning, pejorative-language

I've been trying to think of a word but I failed.

Is there some word or phrase that describes person whose intent is to
discourage people of doing something without actual proof that it is
wrong but purpose of it is to save this person(they are scared they're going to hurt themselves)? Only thinking they know better.

Comment: Your question title and question body do not ask the same question, please can you correct whichever one is wrong (probably the question title). In the question body, they are _warning_ someone, not _accusing_ them.

Comment: Sounds like a know-it-all.

Comment: Also, we try to use full words, not acronyms (**somebody**, not sb)

Comment: Sound a little like a **scaremonger**.

Comment: Thanks everyone for advice. I think @SteveLovell is most accurate, but have another word also at the back of my head. This person claims that they know(assume) something is bad for third but they didn't actually get empirical proof because they were too lazy and in the end discourage people of doing some work.

Comment: e.g.
When people try to start business and person discourages them by saying "it is too risky, go get a job", but they actually didn't start any business at all.

Answer (score 3):

**Naysayer**.

E.g. from [https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naysayer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naysayer) 
"There are always naysayers who say it can't be done."

and from [www.dictionary.com/browse/naysayer](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/naysayer)
"... person who habitually expresses negative or pessimistic views ..."

Comment: I was considering this word too. +1

Comment: You're welcome @user241682.  Please feel free to upvote and or accept.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165899/one-word-for-someone-who-thinks-they-can-do-anything-and-believes-everything-th) which listed *self-righteous*, *know-it-all*, and *hubris* among others

Possible duplicate of [this tread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24222/what-is-a-specific-term-for-people-who-think-that-theyre-always-right) which listed some of above plus *cocksure* (great word!) and *dogmatic* among others

Possible duplicate of [this tread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259004/what-do-you-call-someone-who-thinks-everyone-is-incompetent-doesnt-know-anythi) which listed some of the above plus *patronizing* and *didactic* among others

Also **overprotective** is a word that seems to fit.